# Portrait/Landscape display ios swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I have an application with 2 views.

On the first view, the user enter a login, hits on search button.

The application retrieves through an api information about the login,
is redirected on the second view where it displays information about the login.There is a back button on the second view to go back on the first view to be able to search a different login

In the second view, I treat both cases (Landscape/Portrait)
What happens is the following : first time I enter the login, Portrait and landscape cases are well treated on the result view.

When I go back and search a new login, It will only display the mode in which you entered the second time (if you entered in portrait mode, it will
only display in portrait mode, the same with landscape) Is there something that I should be doing ?

here is the code for the first view :

var login = ""

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var Input: UITextField!

@IBAction func sendlogin(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let text = Input.text, !text.isEmpty {
        login = text
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "callaffiche",  sender: self)
        return
    } else {
        return
    }
}
```

here is the code for the second view (I will only post viewDidLoad, the back button creation along its function and the creation of the imageuser as there are many objects. But all of them are created with the same principle ) AfficheElemts calls the creation of every single object( ButtonBackAffiche, ImageAffiche are called within AfficheElements

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("ds viewdidload")
    let qos = DispatchQoS.userInitiated.qosClass
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: qos)
    queue.sync {
        self.aut.GetToken(completionHandler: { (hasSucceed) in
            if hasSucceed {
                print("good")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.AfficheElements()
                }
            } else {
                print("bad")
            }
        })
    }

}
```

func ButtonBackAffiche () {

```
    let button = UIButton()
    button.restorationIdentifier = "ReturnToSearch"
    button.setTitle("Back", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    button.isEnabled = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ReturnToSearch(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
        button.frame = CGRect (x:CGFloat(180),y:CGFloat(600),width:50,height:30)
    } else {
        button.frame = CGRect (x:CGFloat(350),y:CGFloat(360),width:50,height:30)
    }
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

func ImageAffiche () {



 //Get image (Data) from URL Internet
 let strurl = NSURL(string: image_url)!
 let dtinternet = NSData(contentsOf:strurl as URL)!

 let bongtuyet:UIImageView = UIImageView ()
 if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
     print("portrait ds imageview")
     bongtuyet.frame = CGRect (x:10,y:80,width:30,height:30)
 } else {
     print("landscape ds imageview")
     bongtuyet.frame = CGRect (x:CGFloat(200),y:CGFloat(80),width:90,height:120)
    }

 bongtuyet.image = UIImage(data:dtinternet as Data)
 self.view.addSubview(bongtuyet)


}

func ReturnToSearch(button: UIButton) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ReturnToSearch",  sender: self)
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    print("ds viewwilltransition")
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
        print("portrait")
    } else {
        print("landscape")
    }
    while let subview = self.view.subviews.last {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    AfficheElements()
}
```

One last thing, I have put traces in the code and the creation of the objects, it goes through the right portion of the code but does not display the objects at the right locations.

Comment: Do you override shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations in your ViewControllers?

Comment: No I do not. I only use viewDidLoad to get the json data and display the elements the first time and viewWillTransition to erase the elements end redisplay them if the device rotates

Comment: One more thing, after investigating some more, what happens is that it deletes the objects, and redisplay them but the view display does not seem to get updated. Do I need to do a refresh or something of that sort?

Comment: Why do you remove and add your controls? Why don't you just move them by setting up an autoresizemask or constraints.

Comment: @Spads I am quite new to io swift. That was the easiest way for me to do. I delete all the objects and redraw them. I advanced a little bit. What happens is that the view is not refreshed. I got it working by adding the following line in viewWillTransition : UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "thirdVC") which reinstantiate the whole view. What is the command to just refresh the display. I do not seem to find it.

Comment: You could try UIView::setNeedsLayout(). I personally still think you should sort this with constraints. They really aren't that complex. See https://useyourloaf.com/blog/pain-free-constraints-with-layout-anchors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Spads for taking time to help me.
I finally figured it out. I was not calling the function AfficheElements
int the main queue.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
```

self.AfficheElements()
 }

in viewWillTransition solved it.